# DC motor speed selector switch

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-motor, motor-controller, high-current, selector

I would like to have a switch to select the operation mode of the DC motor (half speed / full speed). The DC motor is 12V 1000W.

Is there a more simple way than using a speed controller (h-bridge)?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a more simple way than using a speed controller (h-bridge)?

Yes.

Power it with two 6 V lead acid batteries. For low speed, power it with the batteries in parallel. For high speed, power it with the batteries in series. You will need a DPDT switch rated for high-current to go from series to parallel.

To recharge the batteries, charge them in parallel with a 6 V charger.

Important: use lead acid batteries, not Lithium-ion batteries. Li-ion batteries are too good and don't play well with connecting in parallel at any random time. Lead acid batteries are not as good, which in this case is a good thing because they naturally limit the charging current between two batteries in parallel at different states of charge.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I had already this idea, but price of 6V batteries is double of 12V ones :/

Comment: How does that compare to the price of a DC motor speed controller? I think the controller is cheaper, and it has many advantages. My advice is: go that route.

Comment: The setup will be used on the boat, and I am afraid that the electronic circuit (even properly protected) wont survive long in conditions on the sea :/